# How to save ajax "success" variable to php variable?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

How can I save the "exportURL + data" data to a php variable? The ajax code is in the same php file, where I need to store that data in a php variable..
Currently its only showing an alert with the data in it, but I would like to store it in a php variable.

```
// URL to Highcharts export server
var exportUrl = 'https://export.highcharts.com/';

// POST parameter for Highcharts export server
var object = {
    options: JSON.stringify(options),
    type: 'image/png',
    async: true
};

// Ajax request
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: exportUrl,
    data: object,
    success: function (data) {

//Save here in a php variable so i can use the value in the php code that follows in my file

    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you want to store it in a PHP variable? Please elaborate what you want to do and it would be easier to point you in some kind of direction.

Comment: Updated my Post. I basically use the ajax script to "export" a chart to an image on a external server. then I want to save the URL to a php variable for later use. the data i need to store in the php variable is "exportUrl + data"

Comment: Try saving it to the session variable and use it in later code.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to capture the data from an ajax submitted to an external server and write to your server, correct?

```js
    // URL to Highcharts export server
    var exportUrl = 'https://export.highcharts.com/';

    options = {};
    // POST parameter for Highcharts export server
    var object = {
        options: JSON.stringify(options),
        type: 'image/png',
        async: true
    };

    // Ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: exportUrl,
        data: object,
        success: function (data) {
           //Submit data from your server
             // Ajax request
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost/teste.php',//this your local file
                data: {'data' : exportUrl+data},
                success: function (data2) {
                    //Response from your server
     //if your teste.php print response. echo "" or die("") ;

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<?php
    //this variable post contains your data sended from ajax
    //print_r($_POST);
    $data = $_POST['data']
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do i need to write into "http://localhost/yoursystemAction"? I basically want the value of "exportUrl + data" stored in a php variable in the same file. Thanks! :)

Comment: In second ajax use this 

     data: {'data':data, 'url': exportUrl}

Comment: Okay, and how to save it into a php variable then ?

Comment: in your local server if you have a teste.php.

In url use: **http://localhost/teste.php** 
after in php code try use:

 echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

and then extract to local variable 

$data = $_POST['data']; 
$url = $_POST['url'];

Comment: If my answer helped, I ask you to dial up to help new users. Any doubt I am available.

Comment: Hmm still not working for me.. So i need 2 php files? It didnt not pass the value of the variable to the next php file. and why would i need to use "alert(data2);" ? I only need to save the value "exportUrl + data" to a php variable in the same file.. Thanks!

Comment: Actually you do not need the alert in the second ajax, it was just an example. I'll change the above example to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Can you explain it in part you are having difficulties?

Comment: Okay. So now i did set it up like you said. But the Ajax doesnt seem to execute / pass the variable to the "teste.php" file...

Comment: Send a picture of the problem to make it easier